# I can't access a array with objects inside other object in React Native and Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm currently developing an app with React Native and Redux.

My problem is that whenever I try to access an item of an array, which is inside another object (applicationState), it causes an error saying that its not an object.

[image]

I've tried to retrieve the array item as follows:

```
<Text style={styles.txtQuestion}>{this.props.survey.questions[0].question}</Text>
```

My applicationState:

```
surveySelected: {
        id: Math.random(),
        title: 'Idiomas',
        date: '01/10/2018',
        image: require('../../assets/imgs/enquetesItem/img1.jpg'),
        questions: [
            {
                question: 'Você fala um idioma diferente?',
            },
            {
                question: 'Qual idioma?',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Comment: Try to console.log this.props.survey.questions, it could be undefined at first if your fetching it asynchronously

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. In you application state it is named `surveySelected` while you are trying to reach `survey`.

Comment: I can't access a object inside a array inside another object when is in the (applicationState), but when this object is on (componentState) I can, why?